# Структура данных для хранения миллионов точек

Tags: структуры-данных, алгоритм, c++

Есть три набора данных, каждый из наборов это двумерная таблица, в которой примерно 50 миллионов полей.(~6000 строк и ~8000 столбцов).

Как вообще с таким набором данных оперировать, как его обработать, через что к нему обращаться? (vector, простые указатели, специализированные библиотеки)

Comment: А какие операции Вы собираетесь делать с этими наборами? И каким образом их получаете? Что будете делать с результатами? Как представлена каждая точка?

Именно от этих (и м. б. еще нескольких) вопросов и зависит проект структуры данных.

Comment: если каждая запись по 4 байта, то это всего 183 мб. Поступите банально - используйте один вектор (только сделайте reserve, что бы выделить память сразу). для доступа к вектору как к массиву используйте col*size+row.

Другое дело, если памяти будет не хватать. Тогда данные нужно загружать по кускам.

Comment: Всего 50 миллионов? Храните как угодно, проблем с памятью быть не должно.